# Trouble transferring pictures from an iPhone 3GS to PC

Tags: iphone, graphics, data-recovery, pc, damage

I had dropped my iPhone 3GS and the left bottom corner of the screen had cracked. Now the touch screen nor home button work. I'm able to charge the iPhone with my USB charger but am not able to do anything on it.

I plugged it into a computer using a USB cord to transfer my pictures and videos and it only transfers 4, at the most, before it throws an error.

**Is there anyway I can fix this?** All my daughter's pictures from when she was in the hospital and videos are on my iPhone and I really don't want to lose all my pictures from when she was little! The pictures are the one thing im worried about.

Comment: What about Photo Stream? Did you have it set up?

Comment: no but i had an app to bluetooth pictures from my iphone to screen at any super center to have picture printed.

Comment: Could you provide the error message that it gave you in iTunes? I'm thinking your main two options are (1) try [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/index-c.php) and/or (2) take it to an Apple store to get the phone repaired, or allow them to retrieve the photos for you.

Comment: when i had the iphone plugged into the computer I could see all the picture just couldn't transfer them over

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like the computer is making a connection to the Phone.  Try these different things and you may get some results, and hopefully get your daughters pictures off.

- Try using another USB port on the computer.
- Try using another cable if you have.
- If you have another computer lying around connect it to that and see if it works.
- Try downloading Dropbox to the phone. now you may be asking "how can I type?" if you can find a bluetooth keyboard you can connect it to your phone and use it as a keyboard.  Download dropbox and create an account if you don't already have one and ask Dropbox to upload all your photos to your account.
- If all else fails take it to the Apple store with a usb thumb drive, they might be able to help you pull the photos off.

Hope these can help you get your pictures back!

Comment: how could a turn the bluetoth on from my iphone?

Comment: You can turn it on from the Settings.  What version iOS do you have?

Comment: im not for sure

Comment: Okay if you tap settings, the third option should be Bluetooth you can tap on that to turn it on.  If you don't see it there then it will be under General>Bluetooth.

Comment: okay will i need anything else?

Comment: to turn on Bluetooth no.  Unfortunately you can't transfer photos to the computer using Bluetooth.  You need to either connect it using a cable or use a Cloud based service like Dropbox, Photostream, etc.

Comment: but once i connect the usb could i possibly download an app?

Comment: what about going thru my Apple ID account, could that possibly work?

Comment: If you have iCloud yes, check this document for information on Photo Stream http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4486